# jQuery - One function for border-color but on different sides

Tags: jquery

Hi I want to ask for help in jQuery field. So I have this project as posted below in jsfiddle. You can see that I have a paragraph with a border. There are buttons that change one of the border's sides. There is a button for top,right,bottom and left.

I posted only two of them cause I make them all work but there is a lot of code. For every button I use different function. Is it possible az in the example to use one function for all. They are with the same class name and I think maybe data* attribute will come in handy here but I am not sure how to do it.

Maybe there is a way to write down a function that gets the value of the data* attribute and then the result for every button appear.

Please if you have any ideas post it and I'll try it to see if it is working. I need one function for all not different for every side. Thanks in advance.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#leftBordColor').change(function() {
        $('p').css("border-left-color", $('#leftBordColor').val());
    });
    $('#bottomBordColor').change(function() {
        $('p').css("border-bottom-color", $('#bottomBordColor').val());
    });
});
```

```css
p {
    border: 5px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Долна</td>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="color" name="border_color" value="#ffffff" id="bottomBordColor" class="BordColor" data-border-color="border-bottom-color" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Лява</td>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="color" name="border_color" value="#ffffff" id="leftBordColor" class="BordColor" data-border-color="border-left-color" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br />
    <p> This is only for the example. But the result will be enough for my project too</p>
</body>
```

Comment: You can try `$('#leftBordColor,#bottomBordColor').change(function() {
    $('p').css(this.dataSet.borderColor, $(this).val());
  });`

Answer (score 0):

You can always use [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) for such tasks, where you need to pass some information from an html element to a common function. I have tried to implement it below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".BordColor").on("change", function(){
    var side = $(this).data("border-side");
    var property_name = "border-"+side+"-color";
    var color = $(this).val();
    $('p').css(property_name, color);
  });//.BordColor change
});
```

```css
p {
  border: 5px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Долна</td>
      <td colspan="2">
        <input type="color" data-border-side="bottom" name="border_color" value="#ffffff" id="bottomBordColor" class="BordColor" data-border-color="border-bottom-color" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Лява</td>
      <td colspan="2">
        <input type="color" data-border-side="left" name="border_color" value="#ffffff" id="leftBordColor" class="BordColor" data-border-color="border-left-color" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br />
  <p> This is only for the example. But the result will be enough for my project too</p>


</body>
```

Comment: Thanks mate it helped me a lot for the other properties too.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('change', 'input[name=border_color]', function () {
        var border = $(this).data('border-color');
        $('p').css(border, $(this).val());
    });
});
```

```css
p {
  border: 5px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Долна</td>
      <td colspan="2">
        <input type="color" name="border_color" value="#ffffff" id="bottomBordColor" class="BordColor" data-border-color="border-bottom-color" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Лява</td>
      <td colspan="2">
        <input type="color" name="border_color" value="#ffffff" id="leftBordColor" class="BordColor" data-border-color="border-left-color" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br />
  <p> This is only for the example. But the result will be enough for my project too</p>


</body>
```

Comment: Thanks. Also helped me a lot for other properties. It is good to see people willing to help you. Once more thank you.